# mysqldump-php not working with shared hosting companies database. No command line access or SUPER privilege(s)

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know if **mysqldump-php** can work with shared hosting?  I can get it to work on my local computer (I can get mysqldump to work locally also) but I need a method to backup a database that's hosted with a popular webhosting company. The only method that they offer to their customers is to sign onto phpMyAdmin and download your .sql manually. daily. yourself. no automation allowed. I'm a newbie and I'm going nuts trying to find a solution.

mysqldump-php called for

```
namespace Ifsnop\Mysqldump;

use Exception;
use PDO;
use PDOException;
```

It didn't mention needing command line access or SUPER privilege(s).

Am I using incorrect settings?

Here's the link to the code that I'm using on Github.

https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php#dump-settings

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Mate, find a better hosting company where you don't have to worry about this stuff.

Comment: I know, right?  The money I saved isn't worth the headache they cause.   :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look in the code of ifsnop, and it uses `SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ` before starting the transaction. Global settings are only allowed with the SUPER-privilege (which you don't have on a shared environment, with a good reason ;) ).

You can either:

1. If you have only MyISAM-tables, there is no need for a transaction, so it can be turned off in the config.

   `$dumpConfig = array(
       'single-transaction' => false
   );
   $md = new Mysqldump($db, $user, $pass, $host, 'mysql', $dumpConfig);`
2. or; Change that word `GLOBAL` into `SESSION` (thus modifying the downloaded code).

Comment: Wow!  Worked like a charm (choice #2) since my tables are INNODB.  Thank you so very much for your time and effort!  I'm a total newbie, so I will upvote as soon as I have enough points to do so!

Comment: The 9th of febrary a [commit](https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php/commit/8e5c9df771a882cf96ee002191510728b2b8a948) was made that fixed the above (changing from GLOBAL to SESSION) as it is the best way to ensure integrity without the SUPER privilege.